# Unable to pass raw_input to Python from php

Tags: php, python, parsing, python-2.7

Hello I Have a Python script which will parse the script is as below, it uses 2 inputs

```
import urllib
import urllib2
code, num = raw_input().split(' ')
parse(num,code)
print success
exit()
```

Now i am trying to pass raw_input using php file but it is not working

PHP script is

```
<?php 
$num="36";
$code="a";
$result = exec('python test.py "$code $num"');
echo $result;
?>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing *anything* to `raw_input()`. `raw_input()` reads from the `stdin` pipe, not from the command line.

If you wanted to read from the command line instead, use `sys.argv`:

```
import sys

code, num = sys.argv[1].split()
```

You'll want to use string concatenation to build your PHP call:

```
$result = exec('python test.py "' . $code . ' ' . $num . '"');
```

You can avoid having to split in Python by passing the two values as two *separate* command line arguments (here with quoting, although that is optional for your specific simple case):

```
$result = exec('python test.py "' . $code . '" "' . $num . '"');
```

and in Python use:

```
import sys

code, num = sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: superb. . .worked like a charm. thankyou frnd . . . can u see another doubt of mine, question edited , after assigning variables its not working :( @Martijn

Comment: @user2501866: You need to use string concatenation; PHP does not magically replace `$code` inside a string with the value.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$result = exec('python test.py "$code $num"');
```

Will always pass the raw strings "$code" and "$num". To pass the actual values of the variables, do this:

```
$result = exec('python test.py "'.$code.' '.$num.'"');
```